# UILabel not being changed, glitches occur - Xcode Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, uilabel

In my Swift Xcode project, I am trying to change the text in a UILabel to an integer which is the score.

```
scoreLabel.text = String(score);
```

scoreLabel is a UILabel and score is an integer that is casted to a String, and used as the text for scoreLabel. When I enter this line in my project, my application glitches very severely and I don't know why. What is the best way to display a changing score in Xcode? I want to display an integer on the application screen and have it chnage programmatically. Thanks in advance.

Comment: scoreLabel.text = score.description

Comment: Your problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Well everything works perfectly until I add this line

Comment: Post the rest of the code

Comment: You can try deleting Xcode caches and DerivedData

Comment: where are the Xcode caches? I tried deleting DerivedData and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Usually this kind of stuff happens when you try to modify the UI from a background thread.

Try this:

```
NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock { self.scoreLabel.text = "\(score)" }
```

If that works, then that is your problem.  If not... then I have no idea unfortunately.

Comment: Fixed the issue. Auto-layout must be turned off. Changing the text changes the size of the label, and reloads the storyboard.